# Stata tables to Latex

Tags: tables, lyx

I have been using outreg2 to get tables in tex format, in Stata; and then to Lyx. However,  you always have to make changes to the code: add lines, arrange the notes to the table, change caption of table, etc. (usually after using excel2latex)

Is there an alternative for outreg2? I've seen esttab being more flexible. What command would you recommend for export tables from Sata to tex?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might consider using R. It does indeed take time to switch from Stata to R, but if you are doing economics then you will not regret making the switch. It will free your mind! Best of luck no matter what you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Ben Jann's `estout` suite of commands: http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/ . Very well documented, and very flexible. It has commands that makes LaTeX tables from Stata output (not only regression results, also matrices, summary stats etc ), but it allows you to append/prepend text to lines (eg `\addlinespace` or `cmidrule` from the `booktabs` package), which makes it quite flexible. I find it easier to make the tabular part of the table with Stata/estout, and then use `input{}` to import that into my LaTeX code. Works very well for me!